# creating an android html5 app, Ecplise IDE TO USE

Tags: android, eclipse, html

I am new to creating html5 apps in android. but right now I want to know the best eclipse IDE for android html5 mobile apps and how to set up the project.

Thanks alot. I have done some research but I just get to see studios like aptana, dreamweaver
but they dont help setup project so I can run on android emulator. I would prefer if it eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

you can use any eclipse version or even SDK with ADT provided on android dev site https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Along with this, you can add eclipse plugin for JS & HTML (like javascript editor).

for debugging - you can debug android code easily in eclipse but for JS & HTML, you can test it on browser ( may be using firebug on firefox) or can debug it using console and alerts